# does window.opener work with target="_blank" anchor tags?

Tags: javascript, html

Say I open a new window for a website, on the same domain, by setting the target of an anchor tag to "_blank". Is there a way to access the opening windows DOM?

Comment: Have you tried `window.opener`?

Comment: Have you tried and found that `window.opener` doesn't work?

Comment: Yes. `window.opener` works fine when targeting `_blank`.

Answer (score 5):

I realize this is an old question but for anyone that might stumble upon it, it appears that when using a `target="_blank"` anchor tag window.opener is defined in some browsers by default and not in others (specifically Safari and Firefox have a null window.opener). However, if you add the attribute `rel="opener"` to the anchor tag, it will populate `window.opener` properly.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was going crazy because 'opener' was not working until I found your answer. Probably browsers have disabled opener object by default.

Answer (score -4):

You can understand better window.open on read this* article, but how much I know about it's same thing, but remember, taget="_blank" it's a propertie from HTML and window.open it's a javascript prototype solution, where you use to create a function to add some functionalty for your site.

*https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.open

Comment: the question is about [`window.opener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.opener)

Comment: not necessarily the question posted it's about opening window, not about window.opener, Explosion Pills only suggets to use that.